# Is there such a thing as a wireless laptop cooler? 

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, cooling, cooling-pad, laptop-cooler

I need a wireless laptop cooler (well I hate wires =D)

I've searched around for quite a bit but there isn't one, before I continue searching (in vain) is there even such a thing?

Comment: There is. I'm actually using a wireless one right now. It is small, inexpensive, aesthetically pleasing and surprisingly effective. It's a rock.

Comment: @MarcksThomas You mean one without a fan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://reviews.cnet.com/4321-3121_7-6566035.html) [definitely](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-9700201-1.html)

> The simplest laptop cooling devices are ones that require no moving parts or external power.
>
> We put eight laptop cooling devices to the test, and among the passive, or unpowered, devices we tested, we were particularly impressed by [...] a massive chunk of ABS composite (the same stuff used for Lego bricks and plumbing pipes), that looked like a cutting board with a big "X" on it. A more inelegant computer accessory would be hard to find, but the [winner] was inexpensive, could handle large laptops, and was just as effective as our fan-equipped laptop coolers.

Comment: so you are saying those "wireless" are not "wireless" but rather those that run off without "power" ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that a passive cooler has no wires and is therefore "wireless". You can't seriously be looking for a device that uses 802.11 communications protocols to achieve a cooling effect :-) What does "wireless" mean to you?

Comment: uh wireless = something like bluetooth?

Comment: Please be aware those devices are not laptop "coolers"; they do not cool your lap or your computer. They are laptop insulators; they insulate your lap from your machine's heat if you lay the machine on your lap. If you literally want to cool your lap or computer you must use a device with a powered fan or with phase-change chemicals.

Comment: _something like bluetooth_ heh, heheh! Seriously, for it to be wireless, it would have to be battery powered. Otherwise it's got a USB cable and steals battery power from your laptop. And the passive ones are coolers if they have air slots. They enable air flow, an important concept if you've ever had one of your kids leave one running on their bed. Mmm, the smell of electronic ironing.